# What function can decrease a number with increasing proportion?

Tags: functions

This is function can be used to reduce a number with unfixed proportion: when x equals 0, the subtracted proportion will be 0, that is x * (1-0), and when x equals infinite large, then subtracted proportion will be 1, that is x * (1-1). For some specific example, when x is rather small number such as 200, the output will be 199.9, and when x is pretty large number such as 4000, the output will be 1800, etc.
And in ideal, this function can have a coefficient to control how the decreasing trend will be like. It's kind looks like a root function, but that reduces a number too fast at beginning and too slow at the end.
In practice, it may can be used to calculate how much resistant force to apply or how much a image's pixels will be removed when compress.
If anyone can answer it, thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing to be honest, but $f(x) = x\left(1 - \frac{1}{800}\left(\frac{19x}{100} - 30\right) \right)$ goes through the points you have and increases up until $x = 41500/19$